# How to understand the event which not dispatched by task queue in event loop of spec?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, specifications, w3c

In the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#task-queues):

> Not all events are dispatched using the task queue, many are dispatched during other tasks.

I want to know the "many" and the "other tasks" above refer to what?

Comment: You can trigger an event from Javascript, e.g. `element.click()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search the HTML spec for the phrase *“fire an event”*, you’ll see cases it says *“queue a task to fire an event”* and places it just says *”fire an event“* without *“queue a task”*. [For example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#resource-metadata-management:event-readystatechange-2):

> Each document has a *current document readiness*. … When the value is set, **the user agent must fire an event named `readystatechange` at the `Document` object**.

Compare that language above to the language in [the following spec excerpt](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-link-element:queue-a-task):

> … the user agent must, if the loads were successful, **queue a task to fire an event named `load` at the `link` element**…

So when the spec instead of saying “queue a task to fire an event” just says “fire an event”, then the event doesn’t go into the task queue but instead must essentially be fired synchronously.